# R : warning message : prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

Tags: r, rstudio, prediction

I am new to R
doing my first prediction case

I am using Energy data from this site

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Energy+efficiency#

I loaded the data in SQL Server table

the problem is that when I use these factors `(Surface, Wall, and Roof)`

I get this warning

```
Warning message:
In predict.lm(lr_learn, Pred_Data) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

If i use any 2 of them with any other factors i get my results

just when I use these 3 factors alone or with other factors I get the warning

I dont know why and wonder if someone can help me understand what is going on

this is my code

```
library("RODBC")
con <- odbcConnect("SQLServer")
TData <- sqlQuery(con,"select * from energy where id % 10 <> 0")
PData <-  sqlQuery(con,"select * from energy where id % 10 = 0")
Test_Data <- data.frame(Surface=TData$Surface, Wall=TData$Wall, Roof=TData$Roof, HeatingLoad=TData$HeatingLoad) 
Pred_Data <- data.frame(Surface=PData$Surface, Wall=PData$Wall, Roof=PData$Roof)#, HeatingLoad=PData$HeatingLoad) 
lr_learn <- lm(HeatingLoad~., Test_Data)

#Getting warning here
lr_pred <- predict(lr_learn, Pred_Data)
```

THis is the data of the 3 factors

```
Surface Wall    Roof
--------------------
514.5   294     110.25
563.5   318.5   122.5
588     294     147
612.5   318.5   147
637     343     147
661.5   416.5   122.5
686     245     220.5
710.5   269.5   220.5
735     294     220.5
759.5   318.5   220.5
784     343     220.5
808.5   367.5   220.5
```

Comment: cross validated: [what is rank deficiency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it)

Comment: There are many reasons in the link you provided that may cause this warning, i think the 3 factors are related to each other, yet i could not find the relationship between them, could you or anyone tell me how are they related if they are? i post the data in teh question

Comment: roof area is a linear combination of surface and / or wall. summary of lr_learn should show you that roof has value NA values for Estimate, Std. Error and t values.